# Folder Picker throws an exception on mobile

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal

In my `Page.Loaded`event I have this code:

```
FolderPicker fp = new FolderPicker();
fp.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
fp.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
var f = await fp.PickSingleFolderAsync(); // <-- Exception
...
```

Exceeption Details:

```
Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
```

This works fine on desktop.

I tried setting additional properties in the FolderPicker` but it didn't change anything. I also tried adding capabilities in the manifest.

I've also seen someone suggesting that it might be because the picker is called more than once, but it doesn't seem to be the case here, since `.Loaded` event is called only once.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Have you tried without `fp.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;`?

Comment: Yes. Same thing happens.

Comment: Have you tried with the picker opened somewhere else than Loaded event? (within a button for example)

Comment: ... Ha. That worked :D Is that a bug or a conscious decission on the developers' part?

Comment: I don't have much time now, however this may be connected with events that are being fired when app is launched/navigated. When the picker is activated, the app goes to background and couple of events are fired. I will try to check that later once I return from work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally desktop and mobile app's lifecycle differs a little. Not sure why on mobile the exception is throw in that specific case, however the [MSDN says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker#Windows_Storage_Pickers_FolderPicker_PickSingleFolderAsync), that theoretically exception can occur while the app is snapped. This is not that case, but maybe exception is thrown because the app may be not fully ready. As I've tried with different events, you should be able to open the picker on *GotFocus* event:

```
private async void MainPage_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.GotFocus -= MainPage_GotFocus;
    FolderPicker fp = new FolderPicker();
    fp.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");
    var f = await fp.PickSingleFolderAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to experiment with this and for figuring out the issue in the first place :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `fp.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");`

The ms say you should give it a special type.

You should write `picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");`

Regardless of whether the folder exists in this type of file did not affect.

Just I say : llwr(辣鸡微软)

You need add the special file type but there have nothing.

Comment: I see, thank you! I'll give it a shot in a few minutes :D I followed [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-using-file-and-folder-pickers). It's weird that thy would do it this way if it's not supported.

Comment: Is it throw in `PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder`

Comment: No, it throws on the `.PickSingleFolderAsync();`line. I managed to solve it by moving the code from `.Loaded` event to a `Button.Click` event. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Can you try cut the `SuggestedStartLocation` line?